# Tomcat URL prefix

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I got following URL

```
http://SOMEURL/PREFIX/servlet/test.Home
```

I thought that PREFIX has something to do with, the `<Context path="/PREFIX">` entry. So if i wouldnt set the path it would disappear but it isnt like this. Prefix is still needed.

Because in my html documents i got some Paths to some css Files, which are in the Base Web Content directory under WebContent/css.
And with this prefix they arent founy anymore because it tries to find them in /PREFIX/css..

Should i just create a directory similar to the WebContent directory with PREFIX as name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your webapp to be deployed on `/PREFIX` then you should:

- Put your `<Context>` element in your webapp's `META-INF/context.xml`
- Not use the `prefix` attribute in your `<Context>`
- Name your WAR file PREFIX.war

If you want your webapp to be deployed on `/` (that is, with no prefix), then name your WAR file to `ROOT.war` (case matters: use capitals for `ROOT`).